# Boost Asio Socket issue

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm new to Boost. I'm developing a little server. I have an issue when a client sends a message to my server. My server calls the function to read on the socket twice

this is the code in my client class

```
void ClientManager::ToRecv(void)
{
    this->_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer),
    _strand.wrap(boost::bind(&ClientManager::HandleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error))
    );
}

void ClientManager::HandleRead(boost::system::error_code const & error)
{
    _mutex.lock();
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " client->HandleRead()" << std::endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _buffer.size(); ++i)
    {
         std::cout << _buffer[i]; // I display the message
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    _mutex.unlock();

    this->ToRecv();
 }
```

When a client connects, I call the start function. This is what display in the console when I launch my server:

I create 3 threads.

```
Server Connect
[004FE200] Thread Start
[004FE238] Thread Start
[004FE7C8] Thread Start
```

and this is when i connect a putty client to my server

```
[004FE7C8] acceptor->NewClient()
[004FE7C8] client->Start()
```

and this is what my server displays when the client send "hello world".

```
[004FE238] client->HandleRead()
hello world

[004FE7C8] client->HandleRead()
llo world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what type _buffer is, but it should probably look like this, note `bytes_transferred`.

```
    void ClientManager::HandleRead(boost::system::error_code const & error, size_t bytes_transferred)  
{
        _mutex.lock();
        std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " client->HandleRead()" << std::endl;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes_transferred; ++i)
        {
             std::cout << _buffer[i]; // I display the message
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        _mutex.unlock();

        this->ToRecv();  
}
```

What's with the mutex? Is that rly neccessary?

I would write it something like:

```
void ClientManager::HandleRead(boost::system::error_code const & error, size_t bytes_transferred)  
{
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " client->HandleRead()" << std::endl;
    std::copy(_buffer.begin(), _buffer.begin() + bytes_transferred, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl; 
    this->ToRecv();  
}
```

Now, what you will likely see (and have seen judging from your comments below) is the fact that `HandleRead()` will be called multiple times with only parts of the message included.  If you know the size of the message prior to calling the `read` function, you can use the composed function [async_read()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) instead.  This is a free function in the `boost::asio` namespace.

Comment: _buffer is a boost::array<char, bufferSize> type.

Comment: I followed your advice, now my server doesn't display the same message twice but the server calls twice again the HandleRead function.

Comment: How can I do to avoid the second call of HandleRead ?

Answer (score 0):

I would venture a guess that you initialized `_buffer` to "Hello World" somewhere.

Calling `socket::async_read_some` will not guarantee that all of the data has been read before calling the completion handler.  You could use the composed free functions in the `asio` namespace to do that.

So what's likely happening is that you are getting part of your message in the first call to the handler and the rest in the second call.  However if buffer was already initialized, it will look like you received the message twice.

Change this line to also pass in the placeholder for the number of bytes transferred:

```
_strand.wrap(
   boost::bind(
      &ClientManager::HandleRead,
      this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
```

Then change your `HandleRead()` function appropriately:

```
void ClientManager::HandleRead(
   boost::system::error_code const & error,
   size_t bytes_transferred) // Add bytes_transferred
{
    _mutex.lock();
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id() << " client->HandleRead()" << std::endl;

    // Then -- check the buffer up to the number of bytes transferred:
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes_transferred; ++i)
    {
         std::cout << _buffer[i]; // I display the message
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    _mutex.unlock();

    this->ToRecv();
 }
```

Comment: I followed your advice, now my server doesn't display the same message twice but the server calls twice again the HandleRead function.

Comment: How can I do to avoid the second call of HandleRead ?